# Is there a reason for unpacking a list then putting it back into a list?

Tags: python, list, packing

I'm trying to understand the following Python line:
`result = {'key_A': [*dict_A.keys()], 'key_B': "dummy_string"}`
Result is dictionary that holds a list in Result['key_A'] and string in Result['key_b']. But I'm not sure why the dict_A.keys() has to be unpacked, only to be put into a list again. Is there a reason for this extra unpacking operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3 `.keys` does not return a list, but a `dict_keys` object, so if `list` is required it must be converted.

`[*dict_A.keys()]` is equivalent to `list(dict_A.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

The dict.keys() function returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=keys#dict-views), which represents the changes done to the dictionary.

simply put, changing the dictionary affects the key's object.
example:

```py
a = {'a':1, 'b':2}
b = a.keys()
print(b)
a['c'] = 3
print(b)

Out:
dict_keys(['a', 'b'])
dict_keys(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Therefore, for maintaining the current state of the dictionary keys, convert to list.

Answer (score -1):

The unpacking operator can be used to unpack generators/objects, so instead of having to do `[key for key in dict_A.keys()]`, a user can use `[*dict_A.keys()]`, as it will get each item of the generator and pack it back into a list. This is also similar to using `list(dict_A.keys())`.